Old React Projects: "Compiled with problems: Module not found"
I am trying to deploy a few React old applications but when I test locally I run into this issue:
Compiled with problems:
ERROR in ./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??
ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??
ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-
loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/App.css) 5:36-79

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/background.jpg' in 
'/Users/<user_name>/Downloads/<app_folder>/src'

Here is the original repo:
https://github.com/rixiobarrios/cocktail-recipe
I deleted the node_modules and ran npm install hoping that the issue would go away.

Based on the path in the error, it looks like the app is expecting the file background.jpg to be found in the app's src folder. Looking at the repository you linked, that file doesn't seem to be present. As a first attempt, I'd try adding a file called background.jpg to the src directory.
The place it's being called is in App.css, here, so you could also remove this line and go ahead without the background.
There may be an issue with the pathing since it's actually looking for /background.jpg, so if you want to include it you will need to make sure the path is correct. I would have expected  background-image: url("./background.jpg") if the image was in the same directory.
